# Android xml layout items are not updating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a detail fragment where i have a few items, mostly TextView. I also have a CursorLoader, that onLoadFinished is supposed to set all those values in the layout.

For example in this snippet, it prints out that text is being set to the value that I received from ContentProvider

```
  String dur = this.expected_duration + " " + this.durationUnit;
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "SETTING DURATION " + dur);
    if(dur != null || !"".equals(dur)) {
        if(durationTextView != null) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "SETTING TEXT VIEW " + dur);
            durationTextView.setText(dur);
        }
    }else{
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "FAIL SETTING TEXT VIEW " + dur);
    }
```

[image]

I see the result in the log but this result is never getting to the actual TextView.

I know for a fact that its not a problem of visibility or text font. I have the TextView hightlighted in pink and made sure that the mock text displays on the screen. I have a feeling that I may be creating duplicate fragments that lay one on top of another (not sure if its possible). I can perfectly instantiate all the TextViews and extract all the values but cannot put them together on the screen. Please help. In addition if my theory of duplicate fragments is correct please explain how you tracked it down. Thank you.

My Layout file (just in case)

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jennyeckstein.udacitycoursepicker.DetailActivityFragment"
    >



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/course_subtitle"
                    tools:text="How to Make an Android App"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/course_layout_detail"
                    android:layout_below="@id/course_subtitle"
                   >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/duration"
                    android:background="@color/pink"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:text="333 years"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/course_level"
                    tools:text="ADVANCED"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/begin_course_button"
                android:text="Go to Udacity"
                android:layout_below="@+id/course_layout_detail"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/required_knowledge"
                android:layout_below="@id/begin_course_button"
                tools:text="If you are new to programming and don’t know where to start"
                />



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/required_knowledge"
                android:id="@+id/summary"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/summary"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:id="@+id/syllabus"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/syllabus"
                android:id="@+id/faq"/>



    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Source code on [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jennyEckstein/UdacityCoursePicker)

Layout name: [**fragment_detail.xml**](https://github.com/jennyEckstein/UdacityCoursePicker/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_detail.xml) and 
Fragment name: [**DetailActivityFragment.java**](https://github.com/jennyEckstein/UdacityCoursePicker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jennyeckstein/udacitycoursepicker/DetailActivityFragment.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are loading the details fragment multiple times as you thought might be happening.

In your layout file `activity_detail.xml`, you have a static details fragment on lines 79 - 84:

```
        <fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:name="com.jennyeckstein.udacitycoursepicker.DetailActivityFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

When your app reaches line 42 in method `onCreate` in `DetailActivity.java` it calls `setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);` which loads your first details fragment.

Then on lines 47-49 in the same method, you call

```
    DetailActivityFragment fragment = new DetailActivityFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_detail_container, fragment).commit();
```

which loads a second copy of the details fragment.

In `activity_detail.xml`, trying commenting out lines lines 79 - 84,

```
        <fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:name="com.jennyeckstein.udacitycoursepicker.DetailActivityFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

If you now run your app and select a course, the details screen will open with text showing in your text view with the pink background as desired.

For more information on static versus dynamic fragments you might find the following Android documentation helpful.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @John_Shea, thanx so much, I totally missed it and your solution totally worked. I was going through code and its layout that failed me!!! GREAT JOB!